# Security alert error message

Tags: ssl-certificate

Hi  I am using windows 10 and every few minutes I am getting a security alert about an expired certificate for flogs.com. I may at some point have used their calendar extension but I am sure I deleted the program as now all I can find is a registry key that relates to flogs.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.com/search?q=flogs&form=WNSGPH&qs=AS&cvid=e76c4dec24f643328f2ed7ec58970633&pq=flogs&nclid=F3E1DD3AB0CB06AF70697C998E6BE17C&ts=1453832049341&nclidts=1453832049&tsms=341`

I see the open with for this key is set for chrome.exe.

I guess this is what is causing the problem since it is the only thing on my system that is associated with flogs at all. If I remove this it will create even more complications; this alert is making me crazy.

RL

Comment: Have you tried removing the certificate from your [certificate store](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-vista/view-or-manage-your-certificates)? Have you uninstalled the app correctly?

Comment: Hi I can't find it in the certmgr anywhere is there anyway to search for it?

Comment: Hi Found the search there is no certificate for flogs .com, it seems to be connected to outlook's calendar.